# Free XML IDE (alternative for Stylus Studio)

Tags: gratis, data-visualization, xml

I'm looking for a free alternative to [Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/buy/compare.html)  which is a visual XML editing tool.

Here are my requirements:

- Tree view of XML
- Some type of visual "blocks" view of XML files (I only found this feature in Stylus Studio until now)
- Create XML snippets from XSD (including multi-XSD with more than one file)
- Xpath query support
- Preferably cross-platform

I've already tried [XML copy editor](http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net/), but it does not work for me

Comment: Have a look on XML Notepad from Microsoft. I don't know about XPath and Snippets, but I has a working Tree view.

Comment: Here's the Link: https://xmlnotepad.codeplex.com/

Comment: XML Notepad has moved https://github.com/microsoft/xmlnotepad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that **[XmlSpy](http://www.altova.com/simpledownload2c.html?gclid=CMKHzf3axsgCFYoEwwodE2IBeA)** or **[Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-studio.aspx)** accomplishes the requisites, but I'm not sure about the multi-XSD. However, the applications I mentioned are paid products.

I think you should consider that it could be an impossible task to find a free open-source application that accomplishes all those requisites you need.

Anyways, here below is a table from **Wikipedia** that compares a lot of free and paid XML IDEs, it mentions/compares some of the requisites you need.

If a freeware solution exists, it should be in this list.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XML_editors

[image]

Comment: Thx for your advice and thank you very much for this table. I googled for it with many terms and never found this table. I'll take a look in the "CAM: Content Assembly Mechanism".

Comment: After sometime searching for it, I conclude that is indeed impossible to find a free good alternative for Stylus Studio, so the best way is get some paid option. Let's try

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**XMLmind XML Editor**](https://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/). Here is how it compares to your requirements:

- **free:** yes, as in "gratis"; it is free for personal use and to work on open source projects ([see](https://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/which_license.html)), but it is not open source software itself
- **cross-platform:** yes – Windows, MacOS, Linux and anything running OpenJDK 14
- **tree view of XML:** yes, under "View → XML source"
- **visual blocks view:** yes, when using it together with a stylesheet; try the Docbook example that comes with the editor
- **create XML snippets from XSD:** not yet tested
- **Xpath query support:** not yet tested